# Swift - How to download & display comments under post?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview, comments

I have managed to setup a commenting system for my app (using Parse). and so far I have a button which I click, which then redirects me to a new TVC when it displays my comments and I have the option to write a new one.

What I would like to achieve now, but I'm getting slighty confused, is to display the latest 3 comments below the image like (Instagram or more social networks do nowadays)...I'm just not to sure how to approach this and how to have them repeating or displaying 3 below the Post?!

I have set this up in my storyboard (image Below), I was just playing around hoping I would figure it out! Buttons would be the username, and Label the comment.

If anyone can help me or put me in the correct direction (or link a previous question, I haven't managed to find any) that would be great! possibly even a little explanation of how maybe instagram does it?!

Best regards.

[image]

Comment: explain what you're confused about. if you have the detail TVC then you already have all the data logic required, you just need to put the pieces together in a slightly different way

Comment: Yeh, that's exactly what I need to do, but I'm just confused of how to put in that different way! do I just connect 1 button & label? or do I connect 3 like shown in the image?

Comment: could you actually use the TVC as a child view controller and ask it just to show 3 rows? or a solution similar to that as i guess the cells are actually smaller & with less information...

Comment: hmm, how would I add that TVC as a child view to the first TVC cell (with the post) ? if you think that could work, if you could just help me understand it a little more in an answer I'll definetly give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

You can create another view controller, with similar logic to TVC (it could actually be the same controller in a carefully designed system, which would open the door to sweet comment animations), where each cell in the table view has an instance of that controller whose subview they add. Each of the view controller instances is added to the main controller as a child view controller.

So, the main VC has an array of 'TVC' instances, each configured for the different posts. This array is populated on demand, as the user scrolls - there's no point creating all these controllers if they aren't going to get used.

When you configure the post cell, pass it the controller instance (or it's view if you prefer).

The only complexity is knowing if the post has < 3 comments, in which case the height is less. The 'TVC' controller can tell you that and you can have a simple calculation to determine the height required. Be sure to set an estimated size for the page cells, probably best to assume all cells will be max height.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll give it a go today! sounds very confusing to a beginner like myself!!

Comment: be sure to read about child view controllers first, it's really just a way of building up your UI while logically separating the business logic (code)